# How would I be able to get a value from JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve a value of a JSON file, but I keep getting the error

```
/home/pi/Desktop/asd.py:5: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  print(str(y[['tunnels']['public_url']]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/asd.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(str(y[['tunnels']['public_url']]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
y = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels').content
x = json.loads(y)
print(str(y[['tunnels']['public_url']]))
```

And here is the JSON file from `http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels`:

```
{
  "tunnels": [
    {
      "name": "command_line",
      "uri": "/api/tunnels/command_line",
      "public_url": "tcp://6.tcp.ngrok.io:18592",
      "proto": "tcp",
      "config": {
        "addr": "localhost:25565",
        "inspect": false
      },
      "metrics": {
        "conns": {
          "count": 166,
          "gauge": 0,
          "rate1": 0.017125393007699625,
          "rate5": 0.027720847107677204,
          "rate15": 0.02187693220653439,
          "p50": 1971501053.5,
          "p90": 11939627275.9,
          "p95": 11991631962.25,
          "p99": 19816396509.55
        },
        "http": {
          "count": 0,
          "rate1": 0,
          "rate5": 0,
          "rate15": 0,
          "p50": 0,
          "p90": 0,
          "p95": 0,
          "p99": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "uri": "/api/tunnels"
}
```

No matter how hard I try, I just can't seem to find a way to make this code work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
print(str(y[['tunnels']['public_url']]))
```

There is a pair of unnecessary brackets around `['tunnels']['public_url']` which causes it to be evaluated as a slice of y. That's what caused the exception, although removing the brackets will not help since y is a `Response` object.

Try the following:

```py
import requests
resp = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
resp_json = resp.json()

print(resp_json['tunnels']['public_url'])
```

Comment: I tried to remove the brackets, but it tells me that 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Yes. Removing the brackets will not fix the code, I was just explaining the cause of that one exception. For a full fix, see my answer: JSON (`dict`) data is extracted from the `Response` object using the `.json()` method. I have edited the anwser to reflect this better.

Answer (score 2):

The requests Python module takes care of both retrieving JSON data and decoding it.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
r.json()
```